# unable to resolve the gradle errors in android studio

Tags: c#, android, eclipse

When I sync the project it show `gradle sync completed` and also says `gradle build finished` but when I try to run the app it shows that gradle build finished with one error and error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':financius:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

apply plugin: 'hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.code44.finance'
        targetSdkVersion 23
        minSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 81
        versionName '0.18.3'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_LOCAL_SERVER", "true"
        buildConfigField "String", "LOCAL_SERVER_IP", "\"192.168.0.7\""
        buildConfigField "long", "BUILD_TIME", "" + buildTime() + "L"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        }
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        }
    }


}



dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile project(path: ':common')
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile project(':common')
    compile(name: 'hellocharts-library-1.3', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'org.beanshell:bsh-core:2.0b4'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.4.0'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:1.1.3'
     compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
}

def buildTime() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Do a clean project and try.

Comment: If u check your gradle u can see few duplicate dependencies. Remove those first

Comment: @ArslanAhmed Same error? Did u remove the duplicates?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @ArslanAhmed can u post your manifest

Comment: @ArslanAhmed just for a test case can u downgrade **buildToolsVersion** and try?